# jquery 1.10.2 getJSON not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome, getjson

code like above:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.tesy.com/test/2012data.php", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It works on safari and firefox, but not on chrome.

On chrome, it report error and get failed.

Why?

Chrome: 29.0.1547.65
MacOS: 10.8.5

Comment: What are you getting in Chrome? If you check the raw data from the url, what do you see?

Comment: just a error,get http://www.tesy.com/test/2012data.php failed.I check the raw data from the url, I can see the json data.

Comment: Is that the actual url? That's not JSON, it's HTML.

Comment: It's not the actual url.You can see it http://www.taobao.com/go/rgn/taobao_doodle/year_list.php

Comment: Sorry, all I can add is that it does work on Chrome 30.0 Win 7

Comment: Maybe chrome 29's bug

Comment: I found the reason. It is the chrome extension adblock...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Works in IE. Doesn't work in Chrome. I do not have AdBlock isntalled like MarioDu suggested.